# Installing flex on Mac Parallels

Tags: installation, flex3, parallels

I am trying to install Flex 3 on my Windows 7 Virtual machine (parallels desktop) on my Mac Pro.
The problem seems to be some sort of conflict between the copy of Flex 3 Builder installed on Mac OS X.

The installer tries to install Flex in x:/Program Files/Adobe/Flex Builder 3/ 
but since Parallels Desktop connects all directories, there resides the Flex Builder 3 installation of MAC.

I get this error Log:

!SESSION 2010-04-22 16:09:23.031 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.5.0_11
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate -command install -from file:\C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3 Windose\com.adobe.flexbuilder.update.site/ -featureId com.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.standalone -version 3.0.214193
Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate -command install -from file:\C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3 Windose\com.adobe.flexbuilder.update.site/ -featureId com.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.standalone -version 3.0.214193

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.core 4 0 2010-04-22 16:09:29.187
!MESSAGE Cannot install featurecom.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.standalone 3.0.214193

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the solution was deactivate the option "enable share profile" on the parallels virtual machine options (well, i am not sure if on english his name is that).

After it i could install any program (including flex builder) without problems. :)